# how to get antecedent version of google chrome ?

Tags: google-chrome, version

My google chrome version is **version 45** . I need to test my app using **version 43** . But each time I try to install version 43 I always get the version 45 . I did uninstall chrome and tried to install version 43 but it's  always version 45. how to get version 43 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed a portable version from here:  [google chrome old versions](http://google-chrome-portable.fr.uptodown.com/old)

Answer (score 0):

1) Uninstall Google Chrome (you can keep browsing data)

2) Install older version

3) write specific registry keys

a) for 32 bit

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update]

"Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"=dword:00000000

b) for 64 bit

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Update]
"Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"=dword:00000000

You can copy and paste this two expressions to a file with .reg ending. After double clicking it, both will be applied.

Comment: thank you @Greaka . I've installed Google chrome Portable version 43